# hy build-in with-decorator throws NameError: name 'with_decorator' is not defined

Tags: decorator, hy

I'm trying to run the with-deocorator example from hy manual (https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html?highlight=with-decorator#with-decorator):

```
 (defn inc-decorator [func]
 (fn [value-1 value-2] (func (+ value-1 1) (+ value-2 1))))

 (with-decorator inc-decorator (defn addition [a b] (+ a b)))
 (setv foo (addition 1 1))
 (print foo)
```

but I'm getting an exception:

```
line 4, in <module>
(with-decorator inc-decorator (defn addition [a b] (+ a b)))
NameError: name 'with_decorator' is not defined
```

with_decorator with underscore. I'm trying with the latest stable version of hy. The same thing happens with any code that has with-decorator.

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation.

```
(with-decorator (app.route "/") (defn index [] "Hello World !"))
```

that worked in earlier versions is now done like this:

```
(defn [(.route app "/")] index [] "Hello World !")
```

and

```
(with-decorator (inc-decorator (defn addition [a b] (+ a b)))
```

is now

```
(defn [inc-decorator] addition [a b] (+ a b))
```

Comment: Could you link back to the documentation? I can't seem to find it and searching for "decorator" doesn't really help.

Comment: Documentation on the newest stable version: https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/

Master branch: https://github.com/hylang/hy

And this explains why you cannot find with-decorator: https://github.com/hylang/hy/blob/master/NEWS.rst#removals-1

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah - interesting that the news is disparate from the readthedocs, a bit confusing for someone who tries it out and types "decorator" into the search bar

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying with the latest stable version of hy.

`with-decorator` was recently removed in master, whereas it still existed in 0.20.0, so I think you're mistaken. Check `hy --version`.

Comment: The version is hy 1.0a4+183.gb3920666. I thought it was the stable version, but it seems to be somewhere between stable and master. Stable version still has documentation on with-decorator.
A lot of changes, seems good